# Не завершается состояние aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram, sqlite3, state, конечные-автоматы

Всем здравствуйте, недавно начал изучать ботов, сейчас знакомлюсь с `конечными автоматами`. Нужно получать у пользователя номер или почту в зависимости от его выбора. Всё привязано к inline-кнопкам, и нажимая на любую, срабатывает только state, который выше(*т.е. записывает номера в почту*).
Причём он в callback_queryhandler получения номера попадает(*выводит:"Пожалуйста, введите номер, начиная с 7 и не используя пробелы."*), но дальше не идёт. Попробовал собрать их в один класс/развести по отдельным, но теперь ничего вообще не обрабатывается. Не судите строго, но в чём проблема? Часть кода прилагается.

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text="Getemail")
async def state_email(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.message.answer("Пожалуйста, введите почту.", reply_markup=cancel_kb)
    await waiting_for_email.set()
    await call.answer()

@dp.message_handler(state=waiting_for_email)
async def get_email(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    regex = "^[a-zA-Z0-9@_.-]+$"
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    if pattern.match(message.text) == False:
        await message.answer("Почта указана неверно.")
        return
    cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO Emails VALUES(\'{message.text}\', \'{message.from_user.full_name}\', \'{comp}\');")
    conn.commit()
    await message.answer("Спасибо! Бегу передавать ваши данные.", reply_markup=rtrn_kb)
    await state.finish()

@dp.callback_query_handler(text="Getnumber")
async def state_number(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.message.answer("Пожалуйста, введите номер, начиная с 7 и не используя пробелы.", reply_markup=cancel_kb)
    await waiting_for_number.set()
    await call.answer()

@dp.message_handler(state=waiting_for_number)
async def get_number(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.text.isdecimal() == False:
        await message.answer("Номер указан неверно.")
        return
    cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO Numbers VALUES({message.text}, \'{message.from_user.full_name}\', \'{comp}\');")
    conn.commit()
    await message.answer("Спасибо! Бегу передавать ваши данные.", reply_markup=rtrn_kb)
    await state.finish()
```

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, то в качестве параметра для `state` обязательно нужно передать класс, и сам стейт. То есть должно быть так: `@dp.message_handler(state=YourStateClass.waiting_for_number)`. Хотя может в новых обновлениях aiogram завезли и новую логику

Comment: Попробовал, теперь вообще номер не записывает, а залетает в пустой хендлер для неправильных запросов.

Comment: Что значит в хендлер для неправильных запросов? Приоритет хендлеров работает по принципу: первый найденный фильтр, который расположен последовательно в вашем коде от верха вниз, поэтому он туда и попадает. Только я пока не могу понять, что еще за пустой хендлер

Comment: Я неправильно назвал, извините. У меня есть хэндлер, что если человек вводит случайный текст, а не действует согласно кнопкам, то бот отвечает, что не знает такой команды. Теперь туда всё залетает.

Comment: Он туда попадает, потому что вы не активировали состояние через `set()`. Когда вы вызовете этот метод, он не будет туда попадать. Скорее всего в качестве хранилища вы используете `MemoryStorage()`, поэтому после перезапуска состояния сбрасываются

Comment: А как же set(), который я указывал здесь:@dp.callback_query_handler(text="Getnumber")
async def state_number(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.message.answer("Пожалуйста, введите номер, начиная с 7 и не используя пробелы.", reply_markup=cancel_kb)
    await waiting_for_number.set()? Данные я сразу скидываю в БД, обходя MemoryStorage().

Comment: Хорошо, допустим вы только что запустили бот. Все состояния на данный момент стерты из памяти. Вы можете писать любые сообщения боту и они будут попадать в ваш хендлер-заглушку. Но как только вы попадаете в участок кода, где вы вызвали метод `set()`, бот будет работать в том участке стейтов, которые вы явно указали, и будет работать до тех пор, пока вы не сбросите состояние, или же вызовите метод `state.finish()`. А по моему мнению проблема ваша в том, что вы где-то неверно указали состояние, не указав ее класс.

Comment: https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/finite_state_machine_example.html а вот ссылка на оф. документацию, как правильно строить состояния

Comment: Благодарю, спасибо, что ответили, сейчас гляну.